# Memory Leak, Other Problems with Multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

We started out with a Window-based application in Xcode. In the `AppDelegate' we have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MainMenuViewController *mvc = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = mvc;
    [mvc release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

`MainMenuViewController` can create one of several other `UIViewController`-derived classes, which also allow the user to go back to the main menu. In `MainMenuViewController`, we have the following:

```
SecondLevelViewController* slvc = [[SecondLevelViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondLevelViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view.window addSubview:slvc.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

`SecondLevelViewController` has similar code going back to the main menu. This works, but ends up creating a bunch of instances of both classes after going back and forth several times and clearly needs to be done in some other way. While Instruments does not report any memory leaks, the application's total memory use continues to grow and the number of live allocated instances of the view controllers does too.

We thought that the call to `removeFromSuperview` would deallocate the previous view controller, but that is not happening even though the documentation says it should.

We also noticed that a call to `release` was needed

```
SecondLevelViewController* slvc = [[SecondLevelViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondLevelViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view.window addSubview:slvc.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[slvc release];  // < < < added this line
```

but that resulted in `SIGABRT` and `unrecognized selector sent to...`.

A `UINavigationViewController` would not quite work for us because the user needs to be able to go back to the main menu regardless of how deep he is in the menu heirarchy.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a leak if there is still a reference to it. Try Heapshot, there is a great tutorial at: [bbum's weblog-o-mat](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/)

In:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:slvc.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

You are just using the `slvc` to create the `slvc.view`, why not just create the view since no ViewController is needed.

Re: UINavigationViewController would not quite work for us
Have you looked at:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: I'll check out Heapshot when I get the chance, thanks. As for why a view controller, my understanding of the Apple documentation is that a view controller handles each screenful of data. There's also the issue of the associated NIB file and so on.